# Use str_pad() to function as a TAB in PHP

Tags: php

```
$emptyStr = ".........";
$whichwrong .= "{$Ss[$s]}\n";
$whichwrong .= $emptyStr . "Question: $questionNum || Answer: {$userAnswers[$s][$q]}\n";
```

Prints out:

```
1. Medication Errors:
.........Question: 2 || Answer: b
.........Question: 4 || Answer: b
2. About Restraints:
.........Question: 3 || Answer: c
3. About Pain Assessment And Management:
.........Question: 2 || Answer: c
.........Question: 3 || Answer: b
4. About Universal Protocol:
.........Question: 1 || Answer: b
.........Question: 2 || Answer: b
```

I am looking to put space instead of the "."
I did the following but it did not work:

```
$emptyStr = "";
$whichwrong .= str_pad($emptyStr, 10) . "Question: $questionNum || Answer: {$userAnswers[$s][$q]}\n";
```

But it did not include the 10 spaces before the "Question..."

Any idea how to resolve it?

**UPDATE [RESOLVED]**:
I used the following and it worked:

```
$whichwrong .= "<span style='padding-left: 25px;'></span>" . "Question: $questionNum || Answer: {$userAnswers[$s][$q]}\n";
```

Comment: you are using an empty string as padding instead of a space...

Comment: Are you sending this to a web browser (which will reduce multiple whitespaces to a single space character) or to the command line?

Comment: I am using Web Browser.

Comment: html? use a table\css appropriate markup

Comment: @mark, a web browser wil not reduce multiple whitespace to a single space. The space is still there, it simply wont show up in the rendered DOM. Simply looking at the source code or print in <pre></pre> tags will neatly show up the spaces

Comment: @Dagon: a table? I would rather advise a definition list `<dl>`.

Comment: it looks some what like tabular data to me - however the point is **HTML** not plain text.

Comment: Updated my code. @Dagon You gave me the idea. Thanks! You want to "answer" it so I can accept?

Comment: sure, not a large answer, any one else can add there markup recompilations if they like :-)

Comment: But since you answered the question I would like for you to get credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the output is being displayed by a browser you want to use HTML (a web browser collapses white-space).  Use a  tag around the output, or a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) in the code for the desired result.